# How can I remove the email in the end of the url

Tags: regex, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce. I don't know which plugin caused the issue with the url

```
https://example.com/color/black/page/23/support@domain.com
https://example.com/shop/march-for-science-on-washington-dc-t-shirt/support@domain.com
```

Is there anyway to track down which one made these url on Google Webmaster?

I'm looking for the solution to rewrite these urls either.
For example, it will remove the email and return to the correct url:

```
https://example.com/color/black/page/23/
https://example.com/shop/march-for-science-on-washington-dc-t-shirt/
```

Comment: Please check if `https://example.com/color/black/page/23/support@domain.com` and `https://example.com/color/black/page/23/` are opening the same page. I don't work with WooCommerce but if the 2 url are opening the same page it may be a `.htaccess` mode rewrite problem. If it's an other thing you may use javascript to rewrite the url, although this is not the solution.  You should find the origin of the problem.

Comment: No, they aren't. It's really weird. It happened recently.

Answer (score 0):

I used nginx to rewrite it

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/support@domain.com /$1 permanent;
```